# How to fix VMs no longer working on Android 12

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-12

After the Android 12, VM apss such as VMOS no longer work, sorry if this the wrong place for asking this question but I can't find any answer to that, and it's obviously not happening to me only, beacuse every new review for these apps is "not working", and Im sure they work on Android 11.
Basically when you start the VM it is just black screen so it is unusable. tried reinstall, did not work.
Is there any other way of emulating Android on Android itself?

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the vmos pro assistant apk which will facilitate developer option access and wireless ADB access as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).